# Run stored procedure that use catalog procedures of SSIS with windows user with minimum rights

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I need run `.dtsx` packages mounted in SSIS catalog with parameters, throught an stored procedure, because one aplication fired dtsx  using stored procedure with parameter values

I have created the stored procedure using

1. SSISDB.Catalog.Create_Execution
2. Set_Execution_Parameter_Value and
3. Start_Execution.

This works, but for run the user need have  db_owner privilegies on principal_db and ssis_admin on SSISD this will only run if the executing user is a windows account, no problem with this but I need the windows account have minimal rigths on principal_db, I know I can't do it using Sql user because is necesary an windows account but when I create my procedure give execution permition for execute stored proc to an win user in the principal database, create the win user on SSISDB and give permision on catalog procedures

1. SSISDB.Catalog.Create_Execution
2. Set_Execution_Parameter_Value
3. Start_Execution

and add to my stored procedure the clause "execute as owner",show me next error
I tried using Execute As and specifying a windows account but I get the error

> The current security context cannot be reverted. Please switch to the
>   original database where 'Execute As' was called and try it again.

I tried using "execute as self" and when I try run the procedure with another win user (that give permision) show me is necesary windows account.

My user has permision on

1. db_owner
2. sysadmin and
3. ssis_admin

I think I need come into my permissions to an user for execute this, considering that my procedure working with 2 databases principal_db (where record my procedure) and SSISDB (where live the catalog procedures for create execution and put parameters).

Somebody can help me?

Comment: I just ran into this issue, exact same thing. Everything works until I try to execute packages using start_execution as a different user. Did you ever find a work around? I am thinking about calling a job or something outside of SQL.

Answer (score 0):

SSIDB admin permission required to run DTSX package.

Package references DB2 proc, needing DBO so proc MUST have EXECUTE as OWNER
AND Proc has GRANT Execute to Win User

Schedule job step owned by WIN USER... this so? and fails?